# web.config location path permission issue

Tags: asp.net, permissions, web-config

I have a folder that is restricted and only for logged in user. So I wrote these lines:

```
<location path="ABC">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

However there is a single file on which I do not want to put any restrictions. What settings should I configure in location tag?

Please don't tell me to move that particular file out of the folder because that is not possible because it is being referenced at many places and I don't want to get messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the page you want no restrictions on, like this:

```
<location path="ABC">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="ABC/SomeFile.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web> 
</location>
```